# In Python when we say print("hello"), is an object with "hello" created and stored on heap and then printed or it's just print without an object?

Tags: python

I am new to Python.

In Python when we say `print("hello")`, is an object with `"hello"` created and stored on heap and then printed or it's just `print` without an object?

Comment: Well, in CPython, `'hello'` the `str` object is cached by the compiler, but that is an optimization

Comment: But the way you think about it is correct

Comment: And really, just stop thinking about the heap in Python. Python is a memory managed language, the way this works is an implementation detail. in CPython, **all objects** (i.e. everything) is allocated on a privately managed heap.

Answer (score 4):

You can try [to disassemble](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) it and you'll see. Python is an interpreted language with its interpreter being a virtual machine (think assembly compiled to machine instructions, but a bit abstracted from the hardware layer to the software layer).

For disassembling Python provides an easy [`dis.dis()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.dis) function.

```py
import dis

def hello():
    print("hello")

dis.dis(hello)
```

It creates the value (I'd guess while parsing, but don't quote me on that. I'd need to check the CPython's code for that) as a constant and then loads it back in the VM when using the `print` function's C implementation.

Now *where* it's created is dependent on the underlying Python language interpreter, in this case CPython (and PyPy is another one).  For CPython it'd be this:

> Memory management in Python involves a private heap containing all Python objects and data structures. ([ref](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memory.html))

Not guaranteed for Python as an independent language, but most likely yes, it'd be on heap due to `"hello"` string not being encapsulated in a simple data storage ([`int`, `char`, etc, the low level types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Main_types)), but in a complex C structure. Or better said a Python object ([`PyObject`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27683764/5994041)), which is in general thrown on heap with Python's malloc or so called [`PyMalloc`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f4c03484da59049eb62a9bf7777b963e2267d187/Doc/whatsnew/2.3.rst#L1804) or [other malloc-like implementation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memory.html#default-memory-allocators) the interpreter chooses to use either by compile-time options or library detection on the runtime.

```
  4           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('hello')
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 POP_TOP
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

However, as noted in the comments, and as with every modern compiler (so even Python's) the code can be optimized, therefore it can be even thrown into a raw C data storage (e.g. `*char[]` or similar) and then only referenced via the Python's object or whatever the optimization's author wishes. To get better details how it's handled you'd need to check the compiler's code and a bit *after* the compilation step when the optimizations might be handled as well.

A bit simpler disassembling with just the code you have. `dis.dis()` accesses the code block in the `hello()` function, so the result is the same, just the line on the left isn't `4` but a `1`

```
$ cat main.py;echo "---";python -m dis main.py
print("hello")
---
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (print)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 ('hello')
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 POP_TOP
              8 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

Related:

- [Python's memory management](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memory.html)
- [Python's memory pool arena](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f4c03484da59049eb62a9bf7777b963e2267d187/Python/pyarena.c)
- [CPython compiler](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/605f4bf7838dbef86b52c955dc21ab489219490f/Python/compile.c)

Comment: technically, the bytecode is an implementation detail

Comment: Agreed. It might not even be exposed and just shoveled into the VM or executed JIT.

Comment: And yes, that object is created during compilation. It is stored in the code object that is created during this phase, and is actually accessible through `hello.__code__.co_consts` if you want to know some cool instrospection capabilities

Answer (score 1):

I believe it creates a str object which has the method **str**(), which print() calls, then it gets garbage collected afterwards, but I may be wrong

Comment: conceptually this is what happens, although in CPython this is optimized to re-use a pre-cached str object, and it will work that way for other immutable literal expressions

Comment: ok thanks for the clarification