# Creating "C Array" in Python

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, types, ctypes

I am reading a book which is using `ctypes` to create `C Array in python.`

```
import ctypes

class Array:
    def __init__(self, size):        
        array_data_type = ctypes.py_object * size
        self.size = size
        self.memory = array_data_type()
        
        for i in range(size):
            self.memory[i] = None
```

I understand that `self.memory = array_data_type()` is creating a `memory chunk` which is basically a `consecutive memory` having `ctypes.py_object * size` as the total size.

How `self.memory[i]` is related to `self.memory`?

My understanding is that `self.memory` has `no indexing` and it is an object representing `one single memory chunk.`

Comment: self.memory can also be assigned directly using  self.memory = (ctypes.py_object * size)()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.memory` here is an array of  `NULL` `PyObject*` pointers.

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> array_type = ctypes.py_object * 3
>>> array = array_type()
>>> array[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: PyObject is NULL
```

Which means `self.array` can contains three elements of type `Pyobject`([Any Python object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27683778/6699447)). So this is valid.

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> array_type = ctypes.py_object * 3
>>> array = array_type()
>>> for i in range(3):
...     array[i] = f"{i}: test string"
...
>>> array._objects
{'0': '0: test string', '1': '1: test string', '2': '2: test string'}
```

Comment: can you please provide more details on what you mean by `array of  NULL PyObject*` pointers. `?

Comment: @meallhour ctypes already provides an [`Array` class(result of `ctypes.py_object * 3`)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c#L4804) which implements [`getitem`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c#L4551). That's why you are able to index the array elements.

Comment: Also when you instantiate a `ctypes.py_object` it will always be a  `NULL PyObject*` pointer unless you pass a value(ie, `ctypes.py_object(10)`)

Comment: thanks for all your inputs. What is complexity for `array_type = ctypes.py_object * 3`? Is it `O(1)`

Comment: can you please provide your inputs to the question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71624787